# Калькулятор , приоритет умножения и деления C#

Tags: c#, методы, логика, калькулятор

Самодельный калькулятор который принимает значения с ввода пользователя и затем должен посчитать то что он написал, и чтобы учитывался приоритет деления или умножения, к примеру : 2+2 * 2 = 6
Проблема с логикой приоритетов, ломал голову как бы сделать , вроде сделал же , 2+2 * 2 = 6 всё нормально, но почему то когда 2+2*2+2 уже exception выбивает , в чём может быть проблема ? или как правильно сделать логику по приоритетам умножения и деления

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] nums = text.Split('*', '/', '+', '-');
            List<string> symbols = new List<string>();
            SymbolFinder(text, ref symbols);
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
            Prioritets(symbols, nums, ref numbers, ref result);
            Calculation(result, numbers);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private static void SymbolFinder(string text, ref List<string> symbols)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (text[i])
            {
                case '+':
                case '-':
                case '*':
                case '/':
                    symbols.Add(Convert.ToString(text[i]));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Prioritets(List<string> symbols, string[] nums, ref List<string> numbers, ref List<string> result)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < symbols.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (Convert.ToChar(symbols[i]))
            {
                case '*':
                    numbers.Add(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(nums[i]) * Convert.ToInt32(nums[i + 1])));
                    break;
                case '/':
                    numbers.Add(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(nums[i]) / Convert.ToInt32(nums[i + 1])));
                    break;
                case '+':
                    if (i != 0 && (symbols[i - 1] == "*" | symbols[i - 1] == "/"))
                    {
                        result.Add("+");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        numbers.Add(nums[i]);
                        result.Add("+");
                        break;
                    }
                case '-':
                    if (i != 0 && (symbols[i - 1] == "*" | symbols[i - 1] == "/"))
                    {
                        result.Add("-");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        numbers.Add(nums[i]);
                        result.Add("-");
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Calculation(List<string> res , List<string> nums)
    {
        int sum = Convert.ToInt32(nums[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (Convert.ToChar(res[i]))
            {
                case '+':
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(nums[i + 1]);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    sum -= Convert.ToInt32(nums[i + 1]);
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Result of calculation = " + sum + ".");

    }
}
```

P.S. видимо где то ошибка в методе Prioritets

Comment: [Вот](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/56187/) алгоритм обратной польской записи. Как раз используется в таких калькуляторах как у вас.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как хорошо, когда знаешь `Linq`. На самом деле примеры всяких калькуляторов выражений здесь пролетали и ранее, следовало лучше поискать, но из тех что я видел, все с поддержкой скобок и не все с поддержкой приоритета операторов.

Допустим, выражение состоит только из целых положительных чисел, операций `*/+-` и не содержит скобок, тогда код получится такой.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите выражение: ");
    string expString = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Результат: {ParseExpression(expString)}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Ошибка: {ex.Message}");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static readonly char[] supportedOperators = "*/+-".ToCharArray();
private static readonly char[] allDigits = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
private static readonly int[] priorities = new[] { 0, 0, 1, 1 };

private static int ParseExpression(string expString)
{
    expString = expString.Replace(" ", "");
    List<char> ops = expString.Split(allDigits, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s[0]).ToList();
    List<int> numbers = expString.Split(supportedOperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
    if (ops.Count + 1 != numbers.Count)
        throw new FormatException("Некорректное математическое выражение");
    foreach (int priority in priorities.Distinct())
    {
        List<char> operators = new List<char>();
        for (int i = 0; i < priorities.Length; i++)
        {
            if (priorities[i] == priority)
                operators.Add(supportedOperators[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ops.Count; i++)
        {
            if (operators.Contains(ops[i]))
            {
                numbers[i] = Calculate(numbers[i], numbers[i + 1], ops[i]);
                numbers.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                ops.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }

    }
    return numbers[0];
}

private static int Calculate(int left, int right, char op) => op switch
{
    '*' => left * right,
    '/' => left / right,
    '+' => left + right,
    '-' => left - right,
    _ => throw new NotSupportedException("Неподдерживаемый оператор")
};
```

Можно вводить выражение с пробелами, можно без, они игнорируются.

*Разберите как работает этот код, выполните пошагово. Если вам не знаком `Linq` и непонятно то, как я получаю 2 массива с числами и с операторами, вы можете получить их любым другим удобным для вас способом (на самом деле запрос преобразования `.Select` можно заменить простым циклом `foreach`). Вся суть и логика данного алгоритма там, где массивы уже получены, то есть начиная с цикла `foreach`.*

---

Метод `Calculate` в старом дедовском синтаксисе

```cs
private static int Calculate(int left, int right, char op)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case '*': return left * right;
        case '/': return left / right;
        case '+': return left + right;
        case '-': return left - right;
        default: throw new NotSupportedException("Неподдерживаемый оператор");
    }
}
```

Comment: всё понятно кроме метода Calculate , впервые такое вижу) что обозначает => switch ? то что оператор switch используешь над чаром op ? 
а что в самом switche происходит в случае left*right допустим? это значение записывается в numbers[i] ?

Comment: @hekeemje Calculate написан в синтаксисе C# 8.0, для краткости, дописал версию метода в знакомом вам синтаксисе. Технически разницы совершенно никакой.

Comment: Красиво. Но вообще, классика жанра - стек, польская нотация.

Comment: @AK стек - для приоритета скобок. Типа ты пушишь в стек, пока закрывающую скорбку не встретишь, потом достаешь из стека до позиции открывающей. Для приоритета операторов стек не особо подходит, потому что тебе нужно именно умножение в первую очередь, а не последняя операция. Хотя может я просто забыл алгоритм. И суть польской нотации в отделении операторов и операндов, что в принципе у меня здесь и реализовано.

Comment: @AK то есть этот алгоритм подходит для вычисления планарной части выражения, того что внутри скобок. А стек как раз может быть оберткой для работы со скобками.

Comment: заметил проблемку что операция умножения "*" имеет больше приоритет чем деление , то есть при вводе "45-8/7*2-30" оно будет умножать , а потом поделит 8/14 , хотя по идее должно 8/7 и затем полученный результат умножить на 2 и из-за этого результат некорректный
P.S. сделал double вместо int чтобы корректно считалось при делении

Comment: @hekeemje обновил ответ