# Парсинг математического выражения с помощью Regex.Split

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, split

Смотрите, например у меня есть такое выражение `string expression = "(-2)+3";`

Мне нужно его превратить в

`string[] split = { "(" , "-2" , ")" , "+" , "3" };`

Что я пробовал

`string[] split = Regex.Split(expression, @"(\b[-+*\/]|[+-]?\d+|[-+*\/()])").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();`

```
Output
string[] split = { "(" , "-2" , ")" , "+3" };
```

Comment: Вам нужно это распарсить именно регуляркой? Для чего это делается, чтобы вычислить значения выражения?

Comment: @aepot желательно регуляркой. Да, чтобы вычислить значения выражения

Comment: Для чего это делается, чтобы вычислить значения выражения?

Comment: Реализовать парсинг, разбор выражения, расчёт с учётом математических приоритетов операций без использования сторонних библиотек, или компонентов, которые выдают готовый результат (типа DataTable.Compute или подобных)

Comment: Не понимаю причем тут вообще регулярки. Ваш результат string[] split - просто набор символов, как они представлены в строке, то есть простое преобразование строки в массив символов (токенов).

Comment: @vitidev Проблема в том, что в выражениях могут быть унарные минусы, плюсы.
Например, `string expression = "(-1+-2)+(20*2/-4)";`
 
Его нужно превратить в

`string[] split = { "(" , "-1" , "+" , "-2" ,")" ,  "+" , "(" , "20" , "*" , "2" , "/" , "-4" , ")"};`

Comment: Я удалил свой ответ и проголосовал за закрытие вопроса, поскольку этот вопрос очень обширный и затрагивает несколько тем. Парсинг и вычисление математических выражений - это достаточно сложное задание для простого ответа. К тому же, ваш вопрос перешел в разряд "Выполнение учебных заданий", что недопустимо на нашем сайте.

Comment: @Adrei Khotko Мне не нужен "Парсинг и вычисление математических выражений". Мне всего лишь нужен, рабочий Regex для разделение строк. Парсинг и вычисление я сам уже сделал. Надеюсь, я доходчиво объяснил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Реализовать парсинг, разбор выражения, расчёт с учётом математических приоритетов операций без использования сторонних библиотек, или компонентов, которые выдают готовый результат (типа `DataTable.Compute` или подобных)

Вот пример рабочего решения с поддержкой скобок и унарных операторов вам на разбор.

По сути, решение собрано из 3 моих ответов: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174507/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248204/373567) и [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1264362/373567).

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string expression = "(-2)+3";
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Compute(expression));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int Compute(string expression)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expression))
            throw new ArgumentException("Получено пустое выражение", nameof(expression));

        CheckParenthesis(expression);

        return EvaluateParenthesis(expression);
    }

    private static int EvaluateParenthesis(string expression)
    {
        string planarExpression = expression;
        while (planarExpression.Contains('('))
        {
            int clauseStart = planarExpression.IndexOf('(') + 1;
            int clauseEnd = IndexOfRightParenthesis(planarExpression, clauseStart);
            string clause = planarExpression.Substring(clauseStart, clauseEnd - clauseStart);
            planarExpression = planarExpression.Replace("(" + clause + ")", EvaluateParenthesis(clause).ToString());
        }
        return ParseExpression(planarExpression);
    }

    private static int IndexOfRightParenthesis(string expression, int start)
    {
        int c = 1;
        for (int i = start; i < expression.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (expression[i])
            {
                case '(': c++; break;
                case ')': c--; break;
            }
            if (c == 0) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static void CheckParenthesis(string expression)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char c in expression)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '(': i++; break;
                case ')': i--; break;
            }
            if (i < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Не хватает '('", nameof(expression));
        }
        if (i > 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Не хватает ')'", nameof(expression));
    }

    private static readonly char[] supportedOperators = new[] { '*', '/', '+', '-' };
    private static readonly int[] priorities = new[] { 0, 0, 1, 1 };

    private static int ParseExpression(string expression)
    {
        List<char> ops = new List<char>();
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        string[] tokens = Regex.Split(expression.Replace(" ", ""), @"(\b[-+*\/]|[+-]?\d+|[-+*\/])").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();

        foreach(string token in tokens)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(token, out int number))
                numbers.Add(number);
            else
                ops.Add(token[0]);
        }
        
        if (ops.Count + 1 != numbers.Count)
            throw new FormatException("Ошибка в выражении");

        foreach (int priority in priorities.Distinct())
        {
            List<char> operators = new List<char>();
            for (int i = 0; i < priorities.Length; i++)
            {
                if (priorities[i] == priority)
                    operators.Add(supportedOperators[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < ops.Count; i++)
            {
                if (operators.Contains(ops[i]))
                {
                    numbers[i] = Calculate(numbers[i], numbers[i + 1], ops[i]);
                    numbers.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                    ops.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        return numbers[0];
    }

    private static int Calculate(int left, int right, char op)
    {
        switch (op)
        {
            case '*': return left * right;
            case '/': return left / right;
            case '+': return left + right;
            case '-': return left - right;
            default: throw new NotSupportedException("Неподдерживаемый оператор");
        }
    }
}
```

На гениальность не претендую, так же считаю, что решение не совсем оптимальное, но работает. Суть идеи в том, что регуляркой разбирать нужно уже строку для вычисления без скобок, а скобки обрабатывать отдельно.

- `(-1+-2)+(20*2/-4)` результат `-13`
- `(-2)+3` результат `1`