# Как поместить пробелы между символами в выражениях?

Tags: c#, .net

Мне нужно, чтобы между "+ - * /" и т.д. помещался 1 пробел, но не трогал цифры и скобки, например:

```
ВВОД: (5+5 )   -  16  /   4
ВЫВОД: (5 + 5) - 16 / 4
```

Comment: Заменить все пробелы на ничего, потом все знаки на строку " <знак> ". Это если в пару строк через `string.Replace`. Если в чуть побольше - ну, пробежаться циклом, смотреть предыдущий и следующий знаки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string output = input.Replace(" ", "");
foreach (char c in "+-*/")
{
    output = output.Replace($"{c}", $" {c} ");
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

```
(5+5 )   -  16  /   4
(5 + 5) - 16 / 4
```

Если нужна более глубокая логика форматирования, например с функциями или унарными знаками, то проще будет спарсить выражение в обратную польскую запись и затем отформатировать обратно. Что-то [типа этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266812/373567) может помочь.