# срез массива в C#

Tags: c#, массивы, срез

```
    public static string add(string expression)
{
    string[] example = expression.Split(" ");
    string result = "";
    while (example.Contains("-"))
    {
        int ch_index=Array.IndexOf(example, "+");
        double result_calc = Convert.ToDouble(example[ch_index - 1]) + Convert.ToDouble(example[ch_index + 1]);
        result+=
    }
    return result;
}
```

надо чтобы в result записывалось выражение стоящее перед выражением со знаком + , потом результат сложения, потом выражение после выражения знаком +, но я не не знаю как сделать срез массива в python я сделал это так: `self.expression = self.expression[:add_index-1] + [str(add_result)] + self.expression[add_index+2:]` а как это сделать в С#?

Comment: Приведите припер, что передаете методу и что хотите получить. Методы и классы в C# надо называть с большой буквы.

Comment: Что этот код должен делать? [Это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266812/373567)? Объясните человеческими словами, какую задачу решаете.

Comment: я делаю калькулятор и мне нужно написать метод ля сложения например входные данные: 67- 34 + 45 split разделяет на ["67", "-", "34", "+", "45"], в результате должно получиться 67 - 79

Comment: `example.Contains("-")` а при чем тут минус?

Comment: опечатка, должен быть +

Comment: ссылка на решение чуть выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> входные данные: 67- 34 + 45
> должно получиться: 67 - 79

Странная, конечно, арифметика...
Сделать можно так:

```
string Add(string expression)
{
    string[] splitted = expression.Split(" ");
    int index = Array.IndexOf(splitted, "+");

    if (index >= 0)
    {
        double sum = double.Parse(splitted[index - 1]) + double.Parse(splitted[index + 1]);
        string result = string.Concat(splitted.Take(index - 1)) + sum + string.Concat(splitted.Skip(index + 2));
        return result;
    }
    return expression;
}
```

Здесь использованы LINQ-методы `Take` и `Skip`, которые, соответственно, берут и пропускают указанное количество элементов.
Метод `string.Concat` преобразует последовательность элементов в строку.

```
Console.WriteLine(Add("67 - 34 + 45")); // 67-79
```

---