# C# проверка деления на ноль в Калькуляторе

Tags: c#, исключения, деление

написал калькулятор с учетом приоритетов , и теперь осталось сделать так чтобы при делении на ноль выводилось сообщение что на ноль делить нельзя
когда делишь на ноль , то результат получается "?" , и Exception отловить не отловишь чтобы вывести сообщение , как ещё можно сделать чтобы поймать деление на ноль и вывести сообщение ?
как вариант в строке искать "/0" и выводить сообщение, но такой себе способ, может есть что то поумней

```
public void ProcessStart(string text)
        {
            List<char> symbols = SymbolFinder(text);
            string[] nums = text.Split('*', '/', '+', '-');
            List<double> numbers = FindNum(nums);
            Console.WriteLine($"Результат: {Prioritets(symbols, numbers)}");
        }

        public List<double> FindNum(string[] nums)
        {
            List<double> numbers = new List<double>();

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                numbers.Add(Convert.ToDouble(nums[i]));
            }

            return numbers;
        }

        public List<char> SymbolFinder(string text)
        {
            List<char> symbols = new List<char>();

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (text[i])
                {
                    case '+':
                    case '-':
                    case '*':
                    case '/':
                        symbols.Add(text[i]);
                        break;
                }
            }

            return symbols;
        }

        public double Prioritets(List<char> symbols, List<double> numbers)
        {
            char[] supportedOperators = { '*', '/', '+', '-' };
            int[] priorities = { 0, 0, 1, 1 };

            foreach (int priority in priorities.Distinct())
            {
                List<char> operators = new List<char>();

                for (int i = 0; i < priorities.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (priorities[i] == priority)
                        operators.Add(supportedOperators[i]);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < symbols.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (operators.Contains(symbols[i]))
                    {
                        numbers[i] = Calculate(numbers[i], numbers[i + 1], symbols[i]);
                        numbers.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                        symbols.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                }

            }

            return numbers[0];
        }

        public double Calculate(double left, double right, char op)
        {
            double num = 0;

            switch (op)
            {
                case '/':
                    num = left / right;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    num = left * right;
                    break;
                case '+':
                    num = left + right;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    num = left - right;
                    break;
            }

            return num;
        }
```

Comment: исключение [DivideByZeroException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=net-6.0) возникает при деление на 0

Comment: Кстати, [вот что нашел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248204/373567) и [вот еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266812/373567).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Деление `double` на `0` допустимо и оно возвращает `double.Infinity` в отличии от целочисленного деления, которое бросает исключение `DivideByZeroException`. Поэтому здесь следует бросить исключение вручную.

```cs
case '/':
    if (right == 0)
        throw new DivideByZeroException("Попытка деления на ноль.");
    num = left / right;
    break;
```

Теперь осталось только поймать и обработать исключение.

```cs
try
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Результат: {Prioritets(symbols, numbers)}");
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: похоже опечатка в названии исключения

Comment: @Grundy исправлено, спасибо

Comment: @aepot в этом и проблема что как его поймать, так как try catch не помогает, пишет "результат '?' " и не отлавливает что было деление на ноль

Comment: @hekeemje дополнил ответ.

Comment: @aepot отлично, работает, теперь понял почему так, спасибо